# mySQL INNER JOIN a Better Option?

Tags: php, mysql

Would doing an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN work better for this? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
$customSQL = "SELECT * FROM customFieldNames";
                    $customQRY = mysql_query($customSQL);
                    while ($customOBJ = mysql_fetch_object($customQRY)){
                        $cvSQL = "SELECT `VALUE` FROM customFieldValues WHERE FIELDID = '".$customOBJ->FIELDID."' AND MEMID = '".$memFetch['MEMID']."'";
                        $cvQRY = mysql_query($cvSQL);
                        $cvFetch = mysql_fetch_array($cvQRY);
                        echo '<tr><td>'.$customOBJ->FIELDNAME.'</td><td><input type="text" name="cv_'.$customOBJ->FIELDNAME.'" value="'.$cvFetch['VALUE'].'" /></td></tr>';
                    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description, in words, of what you're trying to achieve, rather than forcing us to interpret the code and infer your intentions. This will lead to better answers. Further, it would help to have a look at your schema; where does "MEMID" come from? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something of this kind

```
//this is just a sample to let you know how it can be

select c1.somefield, c2.somefield from customFieldNames c1
left join customFieldValues c2 on(c1.somefieldId = c2.somefildId)
where 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is equivalent to performing an `INNER JOIN`, in that it won't print anything unless there's a match between the two tables. Specifically, it's equivalent to this `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT customFieldNames.FIELDNAME,
       customFieldValues.VALUE
  FROM customFieldNames
  JOIN customFieldValues
    ON customFieldNames.FIELDID = customFieldValues.FIELDID
 WHERE customFieldValues.MEMID = ...
```